# Adding calculated column to query result in Korma

Tags: clojure, korma

How do I do the equivalent of

```
SELECT *, id=1 AS calc_column FROM table
```

in Korma? (Obviously, `id=1` is just a simple example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Korma has `sqlfn` which can be used in `fields` as show [here](https://github.com/korma/Korma/blob/master/test/korma/test/core.clj#L234). If even that doesn't fit your need then you always have the [`raw`](https://github.com/korma/Korma/blob/master/src/korma/core.clj#L394) function to feed in raw sql in main query.